# Writing a program using the trapezoidal rule

Tags: numerical-methods

> Write a program to evaluate $I=\int_a^bf(x)dx$ using the trapezoidal
>   rule with $n$ subdivisions, calling the result $I_n$. Use the program
>   to calculate the following integrals with $n=2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256$.
>   Analyze empirically the rate of convergences of $I_n$ to $I$ by
>   calculating the ratios $R_n=\frac{I_{2n}-I_n}{I_{4n}-I_{2n}}$.
>
> a.$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{2+cos(x)}$
>
> b.$\int_{-4}^4\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$
>
> c.$\int_0^1x^{5/2}dx$

My attempt at a pseudo-code:

Initialize $1-$dimensional arrays $I(8)$ and $R(6)$.

input function $\int_a^b f(x)$

for $m=1$ to $8$

$n = 2^m$

$h = \frac{(b - a)}{n}$

$t = f(a) + f(b)$

for $x = a + h$ to $b - h/2$ step $h$

$t = t + 2*f(x)$

next $x$

$t = t*(h/2)$

$I(m)=t$

next $m$

for $r = 1$ to $6$

$R(r)= (I(r+1) - I(r))/(I(r+2) - I(r+1))$

next $r$

Display values in arrays $I$ and $R$.

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: If it's a question about coding, there's a website for that.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster the question is marked in gray.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You mean stack overflow?

Comment: I think that's the one. Anyway, the gray contains *nine* questions, three about each of three integrals, and is presented to us as an order, which does not go down well here, especially when there is no indication that you have given any thought to most of it. Pick out one thing you can't do, explain how far you got in trying to do it, and ask for help from the point where you got stuck.

Comment: Another forum may be more appropriate for this question but anyways. There are several issues with your code. The approximation of the integral and of the error should be separate functions. To evaluate the trapeze approximation, think of it as a dot product between two vectors. If you use, e.g., Matlab, that will not only simplify your code but make it run much faster.

Comment: Also, you should NOT compute $x$ by $x = x+h$, because you might accumulate roundoff error for small $h$. Instead, use $x = x_0+(n-1)h$ where $x_0$ is the starting $x$ and $n$ is the number of steps so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets work an example of the [*Trapezoidal Rule*](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/187/trapezoidal_rule.pdf) algorithm.

Once you have working code, adding larger sample sizes (increasing $n$) is very easy, but lets first work out an example.

Using the Trapezoidal rule, with $n = 4$, we have:

$\displaystyle a = 0, b = 2 \pi ~~\text{and}~~ f(x) = \frac{1}{2 + \cos x}$, so for $\displaystyle n = 4 \Rightarrow h = \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{2 \pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2} ~~\text{and}~~ x_i = a + ih$

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{i} & \text{0} & \text{1} & \text{2} & \text{3} & \text{4}\\ 
\hline
\\x_i & 0 & \frac{\pi}{2} & \frac{\pi}{1} & \frac{3 \pi}{2} & \frac{2 \pi}{1}
\\f(x_i) & 0.333333 & 0.5 & 1 & 0.5 & 0.333333
\end{array}$$

So,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{2+cos(x)} \approx \frac{h}{2}[f(x_0) + 2f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + 2f(x_3) + f(x_4)] = \frac{\pi}{2 \times 2}[0.333333 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 0.333333] = 3.665191.$

Using [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B1%2F%282%2BCos%5Bx%5D%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+2+Pi%7D%5D), we get:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{2+cos(x)} = 3.6275987 $$

If you take more samples, the error should settle and you'll get better approximations.

There are some working code snippets on [*Wiki*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) as this is quite an easy program to implement.

Once you have working code, you can compare to this [*online calculator*](http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/integral/integral.html) for the various $n$ values.

Does that all make sense?

**Update**

Here is a nice write-up on [*error*](http://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Calculus/Section_6.5--Approximate_Integration/Approximate_Integration.pdf) calculations. For your question on $R_n$, all you are doing is filling out a row of calculations at a time and keeping an error estimate at each step and you actually documented this in your algorithm. It is Just comparing your calculated value to the actual value ($I_n$ to $I$), using the formula you gave.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks again Amzoti! I am going to go over what you wrote and implement it in my studies. Thanks!

Comment: Will do, going to go over it now. Thanks!

Comment: Amzoti, I understand everything except two things that I hope you can answer? First is how can I analyze empirically the rate of convergences of $I_n$ to $I$ by calculating the ratios $$R_n=\frac{I_{2n}-I_n}{I_{4n}-I_{2n}}?$$ And also, is there a website like the one you gave me (online calculator) for the "corrected trapezoidal rule"?

Comment: @user60514: It is just a running total of the error so you can show that the error is decreasing as a function of n. I do not know of any online version like that, but you can find such things or slightly modify your code to do the "corrected, which I think means composite" approach. See update in answer.

Comment: Good work, Amzoti! +1